# how to show the solution explorer in Atmel studio

Tags: atmel, atmega32

I want to add a library to my project but I can't find the solution explorer in the Atmel studio 7 where I can add the library

how can I show solution explorer window in Atmel studio??

Comment: please elaborate the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the `Solution Explorer`

[image]

You can open it in `View` -> `Solution Explorer` (`CTRL`+ `ALT`+ `L`).